# Delete duplicate rows in MySQL based on contents of another table

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a MySQL (5.4) table that has some rows with duplicate fields (2-5 copies sometimes) that I'd like to remove, leaving only one. But it's not as simple as just picking the highest or lowest id. The duplicates I'd like to remove are those that don't have corresponding entries in another table.

Table `tb_email_to_members` has `email_id` (auto-incrementing) and `email_address` (and other fields that aren't relevant). For example:

```
email_id    email_address
-------------------------
1           arnold@foo.com
2           foo@foo.com
3           foo@foo.com
4           foo@foo.com
5           jeanluc@foo.com
```

Table `tb_tx` has `tx_id` (auto-incrementing) and `frn_email_id` (and other fields that aren't relevant), where `tb_tx.frn_email_id` matches up with `tb_email_to_members.email_id`. For example:

```
tx_id         frn_email_id
--------------------------
100           5
101           2
102           19
103           19
104           19
105           1
```

I want to remove rows where `email_address` is duplicated one or more times in `tb_email_to_members`, but only when there are NO rows containing `frn_email_id` in `tb_tx` for the `email_id` that comes from `tb_email_to_members`. I need to make sure to leave one row of the duplicates, even if none of them have corresponding entries in `tb_tx`. In the examples above, I want to remove rows 3 and 4 from `tb_email_to_members`, since only row 2 exists in `tb_tx`.

(In essence, `tb_email_to_members` maps email addresses to user accounts in another table yet, and `tb_tx` maps orders to those email addresses from `tb_email_to_members`.)

I can find the duplicates easily, and I see lots of code for deleting duplicates, but not with the tweak of needing to delete only certain duplicates based on the failure of a lookup from another table. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MHardwick and @ShadowRay almost got it right.  The following also checks to make sure the email exists more tan once in `tb_email_to_members`

```
DELETE FROM tb_email_to_members
  WHERE email_id NOT IN (SELECT frn_email_id FROM tb_tx)
    AND email_address IN (SELECT email_address FROM tb_email_to_members GROUP BY email_address HAVING COUNT(email_address) > 1);
```

And obviously changing `DELETE` to `SELECT *` will show you what exactly you're about to delete.

Bonus points for knowing `tb` is short for tidbits?

Comment: Thanks, Steve! This ran correctly, as far as I can tell, on a local test copy of the database (in SELECT * form). The only problem is that it took an awfully long time, and when I tried it on the production server's copy of the database, it didn't finish before a combination of other queries made the site (which is database-driven) entirely unresponsive until I killed the mysql processes. I think I'll have to work on a copy of tb_email_to_members and then replace the main copy afterwards...

Comment: One thing you could do to get around that is run the subqueries (in the where clause) ahead of time and use the result of that in the delete

Comment: I'll ponder that - it's probably just as easy to work on copies of the database that aren't in active use by the site - ensures a backup as well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your question:

```
DELETE FROM tb_email_to_members WHERE email_id NOT IN (select frn_email_id FROM tb_tx);
```

Answer (score 0):

This, I think, does exactly what you want. It removes only the duplicate entries from tb_email_to_members where there is no related row in tb_tx, and leaves all of the originals.

Note that you didn't say anything about removing entries from tb_tx, so the duplicates in that table are left alone (in your example content, rows 102-104).

The approach I'm using here essentially does this, in pseudo code:

DELETE FROM table WHERE id_col IN (
 SUBQUERY that selects an id column and applies a WHERE filter that makes sure each id is *NOT* in (
  another SUBQUERY which only selects the first item from each grouping, very similar to the first SUBQUERY
  )
)

There's another SUBQUERY in there (line 2) wrapping the whole thing up, which prevents MySQL from complaining that you can't select from and modify a table at the same time.

Note: this is likely to be slow if your data set is large. Back up your tables before deleting a lot of data manually!

I realize this is a rather complex query, but it does work.

```sql
DELETE FROM tb_email_to_members WHERE email_id IN (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ids.eid FROM (
      SELECT tb_email_to_members.email_id AS eid, dup.email_id AS eid2, dup.email_address, frn_email_id
      FROM tb_email_to_members
      LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT email_id, email_address FROM tb_email_to_members
        GROUP BY email_address
        HAVING count(email_id) > 1) AS dup
        ON tb_email_to_members.email_address = dup.email_address
      INNER JOIN tb_tx tx ON dup.email_id = tx.frn_email_id
    ) AS ids
    WHERE ids.eid NOT IN (
      SELECT tb_email_to_members.email_id AS eid FROM tb_email_to_members
      LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT email_id, email_address FROM tb_email_to_members
        GROUP BY email_address
        HAVING count(email_id) > 1) AS dup
        ON tb_email_to_members.email_address = dup.email_address
      INNER JOIN tb_tx tx ON dup.email_id = tx.frn_email_id
      GROUP BY dup.email_id
    )
  ) AS foo
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Seth! This didn't end up working, though I'm not sure why. When I ran it in SELECT * form, it found only 21 matches, as opposed to 582 for the solution below.

Comment: I misunderstood the question and as a result went a little nuts with the query. I'm glad you got one that (seems to) work, though.